# javascript create new method

Tags: javascript

using `prototype` method we can create new methods... like...

```
Object.prototype.newMethod=function(){
   // do something
}
```

Here I am defining the `newMethod` with an **anonymous function**... now if I want to **use this method**, I have to use it like: `<object>.newMethod();`

But now I want to create a new method which I can use like: `<object>.newMethod;`... no brackets... How can I do that...??

please don't use any jQuery...

Comment: Simple answer: Don't do that.

Comment: If you want to pass a reference to that method, you can just use `<object>.newMethod`, no magic needed. Otherwise I'm not sure what you want to do... do you want to execute a method without calling it?

Comment: I need to trigger the anonymous function using `newMethod` instead of `newMethod()`

Comment: Why is the non-use of `()` necessary/important?

Comment: actually I want to build a method like `<object>.parentNode`... where we don't write `parentNode()`... only `parentNode`... no `()`...

Comment: Well, functions are just objects... you could just attach functions to it, but it really depends on your use case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't really understand *why* you would want to do that, but it *is* possible, albeit with a nasty hacky workaround. What you're actually looking for, AFAIK, is a magic property (like the `someArray.length` property).

```
var foo = {val:'foo'};
foo.length = (function(that)
{
    return function()
    {
        return that.val.length;
    }
})(foo);
//at this point foo.length(); returns 3, but still requires parentheses
//so, build another closure, and assign a valueOf method to the lenth method:
foo.length.valueOf = (function(method)
{
    return function()
    {
        return method();//call the length method
    }
})(foo.length);
console.log(foo.length +1);//logs 4
foo.val += 'bar';
console.log(foo.length);//logs 6
//BUT:: be carefull!!
alert(foo.length);//coerces to string, we haven't redefined the toString method, so the function code will be alerted
alert(foo.length + '');//alerts 6
```

This is just to show you that, *yes* it is theoretically possible, but please, please, don't use this kind of overly polluted hacks... I haven't thoroughly tested this, but ATM, I've already noticed that `console.log(foo.length);` can return a different value, not sure why, yet:

```
foo = {val:'foo'};
foo.length = (function(that){return function(){ return that.val.length;};})(foo);
foo.length.valueOf = (function(method){return function(){return method();};})(foo.length);
foo.length;//returns 3, great
foo.val += 'bar';
console.log(foo.length);//logged 3 at first, now it's back to logging 6!<-- don't trust this is the conclusion
```

Comment: It's the name of an argument, passed to an IIFE, creating a closure... Put simply `that === foo`. Because `(function(that){})(foo);`<-- I declare a function, and invoke it. The function I declared accepts 1 argument, called `that`, and I pass `foo` as its value. The return value of this IIFE is assigned to `foo.length`. This return value is a function, that has _"immutable access"_ to `foo`. It's done because `this` might end up referencing another object, depending on the context, `that` will always point at foo. Same logic applies to `method` (Immediately Invoked Function Expression)

Comment: thanks for your comment @Elias Van Ootegem... I thought `that` is something like `this`... now `that` is clear to me...

Answer (score 5):

Erm, you can't. To call a method, you write parentheses after it. Otherwise you're just referencing it.

The only exception to this rule is when you write something like `new Date`, where the parentheses are implict due to the `new` keyword and only because there are no arguments given.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to call a function without parenthesis would be to define it using [getters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/get) and [setters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/set).

Note these are new to JavaScript 1.8 and are not supported by all browsers.